# Spring Batch -Remote partitioning

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Currently, we are migrating a batch job from java to spring batch. This batch job gets its input from the database and web service. We need to run this job in four servers for increased performance as this job is handling huge data.

Is the above scenario achievable through remote partitioning in spring batch?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share remote partitioning example. you can find all sources [here](https://github.com/gredwhite/spring-batch-remote-execution/tree/master/src/main/java/my/batch/experiments/remote/partitioning)

### Master application:

**batch config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableBatchIntegration
@Import(value = {BrokerConfiguration.class})
public class MasterConfiguration {

    private static final int GRID_SIZE = 3;

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    private final RemotePartitioningMasterStepBuilderFactory masterStepBuilderFactory;


    public MasterConfiguration(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                               RemotePartitioningMasterStepBuilderFactory masterStepBuilderFactory) {

        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.masterStepBuilderFactory = masterStepBuilderFactory;
    }

    /*
     * Configure outbound flow (requests going to workers)
     */
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(requests())
                .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("requests"))
                .get();
    }

    /*
     * Configure inbound flow (replies coming from workers)
     */
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel replies() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("replies"))
                .channel(replies())
                .get();
    }

    /*
     * Configure the master step
     */
    @Bean
    public Step masterStep() {
        return this.masterStepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
                .partitioner("workerStep", new BasicPartitioner())
                .gridSize(GRID_SIZE)
                .outputChannel(requests())
                .inputChannel(replies())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job remotePartitioningJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("remotePartitioningJobMy")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(masterStep())
                .build();
    }

}
```

**partitioner:**

```
public class BasicPartitioner extends SimplePartitioner {

    private static final String PARTITION_KEY = "partition";

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitions = super.partition(gridSize);
        int i = 0;
        for (ExecutionContext context : partitions.values()) {
            context.put(PARTITION_KEY, PARTITION_KEY + (i++));
        }
        return partitions;
    }

}
```

**broker config:**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:remote-partitioning.properties")
public class BrokerConfiguration {

    @Value("${broker.url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(this.brokerUrl);
        connectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

}
```

**starter:**

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({BasicPartitioner.class, BrokerConfiguration.class})
public class MasterApplication {

    @Value("${broker.url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MasterApplication.class, args);
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.addConnector(brokerUrl);
        broker.start();
    }
}
```

### Slave application:

**config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableBatchIntegration
@Import(value = {BrokerConfiguration.class})
public class WorkerConfiguration {

    private final RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory workerStepBuilderFactory;


    public WorkerConfiguration(RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory workerStepBuilderFactory) {
        this.workerStepBuilderFactory = workerStepBuilderFactory;
    }

    /*
     * Configure inbound flow (requests coming from the master)
     */
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("requests"))
                .channel(requests())
                .get();
    }

    /*
     * Configure outbound flow (replies going to the master)
     */
    @Bean
    public DirectChannel replies() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(replies())
                .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("replies"))
                .get();
    }

    /*
     * Configure the worker step
     */
    @Bean
    public Step workerStep() {
        return this.workerStepBuilderFactory.get("workerStep")
                .inputChannel(requests())
                .outputChannel(replies())
                .tasklet(tasklet(null))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet tasklet(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['partition']}") String partition) {
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            System.out.println("processing " + partition);
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }

}
```

**starter:**

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({BrokerConfiguration.class})

public class WorkerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WorkerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it correct that master and worker are both spring batch jobs? The master is a batch job which puts a unit or work into a queue for the worker, the worker gets the unit of work, processes it and gives it back to the master, both using spring integration to do so?


I guess it would also be possible to not use a tasklet in the worker step but a spring integration workflow? So that the master would give work to the workers which they process using a larger spring integration workflow?