# Hand work over to Spring Integration workflow using Spring Batch remote partitioning

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I want to write a batch which reads data from a table, partitions the data and hands it over to a Spring Integration workflow.

The batch and the integration workflow are both separate maven projects and the integration project is a dependency in the batch project.

My batch has a very small job-context (xml). Only one partitioner and one tasklet. In this tasklet I'm putting data (hardcoded for testing purposes) into a Spring integration gateway. After that, I'm passing the message into an outbound-channel-adapter, which just prints it to the console.

My batch job-context looks as following:

```
<job id="myJob" incrementer="idIncrementer"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        
        <step id="startTasklet" next="giveToWorkflow">
            <partition step="worker" partitioner="myPartitioner">
                <handler task-executor="taskExecutor" grid-size="1"></handler>
            </partition>
        </step>
        
        <step id="giveToWorkflow">
            <tasklet ref="startTaskletBean">
                <transaction-attributes isolation="DEFAULT"
                    propagation="REQUIRED" timeout="1800" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>

    </job>
    
    <step xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" id="worker">
        <tasklet ref="startTaskletBean">
            <transaction-attributes isolation="DEFAULT"
                propagation="REQUIRED" timeout="1800" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>

    <bean id="startTaskletBean"
        class="com.my.project.WorkerTasklet">
        <property name="gateway" ref="mainGateway" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="myPartitioner"
        class="com.my.project.Partitioner">
    </bean>
```

My integration context looks like follwing:

```
    <int:channel  id="request"/>
    <int:channel  id="reply"/>
    
    <int:gateway id="mainGateway" service-interface="com.my.project.workflow.Einstiegspunkt" default-request-channel="request" />
    
    <int:outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundAdapter" ref="consumerService" method="ausgeben" channel="request"/>
    
    <bean id="consumerService" class="com.my.project.workflow.Ausgabe"/>
    
</beans>
```

As far as I understand it, the Spring Integration project is a normal library in the Spring Batch project. I'm told to use remote partitioning so that multiple instances of the integration workflow can run (concurrently) in their own JVMs. I think that with my current setup with a normal partitioner and no remote partitioner this would not be possible.

I found this project, which I don't quite understand:
[repo](https://github.com/gredwhite/spring-batch-remote-execution/tree/master/src/main/java/my/batch/experiments/remote/partitioning)

It's from this stackoverflow question: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154381/spring-batch-remote-partitioning)

In this example annotations are used for configuration. Am I right in thinking that the manager and the worker are both (seperate) Spring Batches?

Spring Boot is no option for me.

Answer (score 2):

What you have right now is a single application context in a single JVM - just one application as is!

You probably need to learn more what is remote partitioning and how to configure it for Spring Integration channel adapters:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/scalability.html#scalability
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#springBatchIntegration